# Solving $ \left| \frac{-2x-6}{4}  \right| \le 5$ for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

Say I have a statement like:

$$
\left| \frac{-2x-6}{4}  \right| \le 5.
$$

And I want to find the closed interval form of $x$. i.e. I want to know what the maximum and minimum $x$ can be. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get rid of the - inside of the absolute value and have the 
inequality
$${|2x + 6|\over 4} \le 5$$
or 
$$|x + 3| < 10.$$
Now you can use the fact that for real numbers $a$ and $b$, we have ${\rm distance}(a,b) = |a - b|$ and observe that
$|x + 3| = {\rm distance}(x, -3)$.

You now have the inequality  ${\rm distance}(x, -3) < 10$, which yields
$-13 < x < 7$.   This is a nice geometric way to think about the problem.

Answer (score 7):

$|z|\le a$ is the same thing as $-|a|\le z\le|a|$. If you take $z$ to be $(-2x-6)/4$, and $a$ to be $5$, that should get you started.

Answer (score 3):

You can translate the absolute value to two statements:  $\frac{-2x-6}{4} \le 5$ and $-\frac{-2x-6}{4} \le 5$.  Each one gives one end of the interval.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think so, am I trying to solve for 'x' in both of those?

Comment: @InBetween, yes (what then?).

Comment: Sweet! Got it, thanks for the help!